# How to convert office files (docx, xlsx) to google format in c#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-docs

Anyone share the way to convert docx, xlsx, pptx to google format in programmatic. I am uploading through Google Drive API and sharing to users using c#. every time creating a duplicate document when someone edit the file.

I want to convert the file while upload. So i can share the converted file to everyone.

I am using Google Drive v3 api.

Download Code:

```
private static System.IO.MemoryStream DownloadFile(DriveService service, string fileID)
    {
        var request = service.Files.Get(fileID);
        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
        // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
        // download is completed or failed.
        request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (Google.Apis.Download.IDownloadProgress progress) =>
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                        break;
                    }
                case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Completed:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                        //SaveStream(stream, saveTo);
                        break;
                    }
                case Google.Apis.Download.DownloadStatus.Failed:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                        break;
                    }
            }
        };
        request.Download(stream);
        return stream;
    }

    private static void SaveStream(System.IO.MemoryStream stream, string saveTo)
    {
        using (System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(saveTo, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            stream.WriteTo(file);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get you started my friend. Check the [Basic uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#basic_uploads) and [Importing to Google Docs types](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#importing_to_google_docs_types_wzxhzdk18wzxhzdk19) as it shows you how to upload and convert some file types to Google formats.

```
var fileMetadata = new File()
{
    Name = "My Report",
    MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
};
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("files/report.csv",
                        System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    request = driveService.Files.Create(
        fileMetadata, stream, "text/csv");
    request.Fields = "id";
    request.Upload();
}
var file = request.ResponseBody;
Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
```

Comment: Thank you, working great..., but when downloading through api, file was not opening in MS Word or Excel... Is anything needs to change on download? Attached Download code on my question...

Comment: I have done that by using export option. var request = service.Files.Export(fileID, GetMimeType(saveTo));//service.Files.Get(fileID); Thank you...