# Problem loading MS Word docx file to Google Drive with service account

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

When trying to upload a docx-file via Google Drive API v3, it completes with success. I can't understand why an error shows up when trying to open the docx.

[image]

we use Google.Apis.Drive.v3 Version="1.49.0.2065" package and for auth use google service account. Here an example of our code:

```
class Program
{
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
    static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata, DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata };
    static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var GoogleCred = GoogleCredential.FromFile("online-contract-236111-13ccc07ef347.json").CreateScoped(Scopes);
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = GoogleCred,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        var ids = service.Files.GenerateIds().Execute();

        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        // fileMetadata.Name = @"excel1.xlsx";
        fileMetadata.Name = @"КП.docx";
        // fileMetadata.Name = @"present1.pptx";
        string fileId = string.Empty;
        // useing(var fileStream = File.Open(@"c:\temp\present.pptx", FileMode.Open))
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(@"c:\temp\Компред САЦ 2017.docx", FileMode.Open))
        // using (var fileStream = File.Open(@"c:\temp\excel1.xlsx", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var fileUpload = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
            // var fileUpload = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
            // var fileUpload = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            fileUpload.Fields = "id";
            IUploadProgress progress = fileUpload.Upload();
            if (progress.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(progress.Exception);
            }
            else
            {
                fileId = fileUpload.ResponseBody.Id;
                Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + fileId);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

        var permission = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.Permission();
        permission.Type = "anyone";
        permission.Role = "writer";
        var perm = service.Permissions.Create(permission, fileId);
        perm.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine("Premission created!");
        Console.ReadKey();

        Process.Start("explorer.exe", "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + fileId + "/edit");
        // Process.Start("explorer.exe", "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/" + fileId + "/edit");
        // Process.Start("explorer.exe", "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + fileId + "/edit");
        Console.WriteLine("Redirected to browser!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

However, when using the browser and auth in Google Account (Google Chrome), the file opens fine, without any error. When we use Google Drive we create files on our drive and give users edit and use it in public access by fileId.

Please, what is wrong in our end?

Comment: What does the error message say, in English?

Comment: What's the error message? Post the *text* in the question itself, not a screenshot with a non-English message box. `when we use the browser and auth in google account in browser ` that's expected - Google Docs doesn't allow anonymous access unless a document is explicitly shared

Comment: did you convert the file to a google doc format?

Comment: In English error is failed to load file - try again or report an error

Comment: DalmTo, no we do not convert file, how is it?

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, we create file in google drive and share it how it described in google drive reference https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create

Comment: The problem does not exist for file XLSX and PPTX, for those file everythinks works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to DalmTo, from comments. The problem were in google file format. Before upload docx file need convert it to google doc file format like:

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
fileMetadata.Name = @"КП.docx";
fileMetadata.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.document";
```

[More info in Google file format convert question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45767455/1335582)